# /usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Mono: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs

Tags: fonts, alpine-linux

I have install latex 2013(small installation) into [alpine](https://www.alpinelinux.org/) and run it in docker, when I tried to using this command to show alpine font list:

```
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif # fc-list
```

the output is null, how to known the font is avaliable for xelatex? what should I do to make xelatex to load the system fonts? I have tried to using this command to refresh the font:

```
fc-cache -fv
```

shows output like this:

```
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif # fc-cache -fv
Font directories:
    /root/.local/share/fonts
    /usr/local/share/fonts
    /usr/share/fonts
    /root/.fonts
    /usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Mono
    /usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif
    /usr/share/fonts/LM_Roman_10
    /usr/share/fonts/Main
    /usr/share/fonts/noto
    /usr/share/fonts/source-han-sans
    /usr/share/fonts/source-han-serif
    /usr/share/fonts/zh_CN-Adobe
/root/.local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 8 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Mono: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/LM_Roman_10: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/Main: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/noto: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/source-han-sans: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/source-han-serif: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/zh_CN-Adobe: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/root/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Mono: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/LM_Roman_10: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/Main: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/noto: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/source-han-sans: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/source-han-serif: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/zh_CN-Adobe: skipping, looped directory detected
/var/cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/root/.cache/fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
/root/.fontconfig: not cleaning non-existent cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded
```

I check the font folder, it look like this:

```
/usr/share/fonts/IBM_Plex_Serif # ls
IBMPlexSerif-Bold.ttf              IBMPlexSerif-ExtraLightItalic.ttf  IBMPlexSerif-LightItalic.ttf       IBMPlexSerif-Regular.ttf           IBMPlexSerif-Thin.ttf
IBMPlexSerif-BoldItalic.ttf        IBMPlexSerif-Italic.ttf            IBMPlexSerif-Medium.ttf            IBMPlexSerif-SemiBold.ttf          IBMPlexSerif-ThinItalic.ttf
IBMPlexSerif-ExtraLight.ttf        IBMPlexSerif-Light.ttf             IBMPlexSerif-MediumItalic.ttf      IBMPlexSerif-SemiBoldItalic.ttf    OFL.txt
```

seems the alpine did not load the fonts.